# How do I add to a date and then compare it to the current date in Hibernate?

Tags: java, sql, hibernate

I started with the following Hibernate code:

```
@SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
List<Event> events = (List<Event>) session.createQuery(
    "FROM Event e WHERE e.enabled = TRUE e.date + 31557600 < :now"
)
.setDate("now", new Date())
.list();
```

Adding to the date did not work. I looked into using [Criteria](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/core/3.3/api/org/hibernate/Criteria.html) with [Restrictions](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/core/3.3/api/org/hibernate/criterion/Restrictions.html), but I also need to check that the event is enabled. How can I accomplish this date comparison?

Comment: isn't the same if you do the math on the `:now` value that you pass in java instead than doing the operation on the database?

Comment: Good idea! I'm heading out but if you can write code that works I'll accept your answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
Calendar currDate = Calendar.getInstance();
currDate.add(<field>, -31557600); // I guess field will be Calendar.MILLISECOND
```

and then on your query you write

```
@SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
List<Event> events = (List<Event>) session.createQuery(
    "FROM Event e WHERE e.enabled = TRUE e.date > :now"
)
.setDate("now", currDate.getTime())
.list();
```

does this work?

Comment: It worked! It seems so obvious now, that lack of sleep didn't do me very well :D. I made some edits to your answer that make it more clear.